# Why does reading DOM measurements trigger a layout/reflow?

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser, webkit

I often read that changing a style after reading the element's style is a bad practice as it triggers an unnecessary reflow. Consider this code from [here](https://kellegous.com/j/2013/01/26/layout-performance/):

Bad Code:

```
elementA.className = "a-style";
var heightA = elementA.offsetHeight;  // layout is needed
elementB.className = "b-style";       // invalidates the layout
var heightB = elementB.offsetHeight;  // layout is needed again
```

Good code:

```
elementA.className = "a-style";
elementB.className = "b-style";
var heightA = elementA.offsetHeight;   // layout is needed and calculated
var heightB = elementB.offsetHeight;   // layout is up-to-date (no work)
```

I am curious to know why `elementA.offsetHeight` will cause a layout? Here we are simply reading already applied changes, not really applying a change (like in case of `elementA.className = "a-style"`).

Comment: It's likely due to deferred rendering, if you read a property you intercept the deferred part.  So will be slower.

Answer (score 4):

> Here we are simply reading already applied changes...

Not really. Assigning to `className` means the browser has to reflow, but it doesn't mean it *already has* reflowed when you're done assigning. It may wait (in modern browsers, will wait) until its next paint, which won't happen until after the current JavaScript code completes (at least).

But when you read a calculated property like `clientHeight`, the browser has to pause the JavaScript code and reflow the page so it can return an accurate number. So your "good" code does this:

```
elementA.className = "a-style";        // marks the layout stale
elementB.className = "b-style";        // marks the layout stale (no change)
var heightA = elementA.offsetHeight;   // triggers reflow
var heightB = elementB.offsetHeight;   // no need for reflow, the layout isn't stale
```

Comment: Interesting. But what if there are no style changes like assignment of a `class` involved? Will reading `offsetHeight` still cause reflow?

Comment: @maverick - If the layout has already been calculated and is still up to date, as far as I know it doesn't. I should probably delete this answer, though. I can't cite any resources for it and I'm not an expert on reflow dynamics. I think the above is correct, but I'm not sure "I think" is good enough for an SO answer, particularly not one from someone with a high rep due to *other* expertise, which could be misleading... :-)

Comment: I think your answer makes a lot of sense, so its better not to delete :). Even I thought of asynchronous rendering as the culprit when I was posting this question, so "I think" this is the right answer! Let's see if someone can link any valid resources here..

Comment: @maverick - While the advice and this answer are broadly right, I suspect there may be a fair amount of devil in the detail. As well as the question you pose about DOM changes that don't modify the render tree, there's also a question mark over changes that only impact localised parts of the layout, and therefore may only cause partial reflows. This stuff is very implementation dependant and very subject to change as CSS progresses.

Comment: maverick, I second what @Alohci said. :-)

Comment: As someone who wrote a bit on this subject matter, yes this answer is mostly correct. A few points of precision: Current Chrome and FF will wait the next [rendering](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-loop-processing-model:fully-active-9) step before triggering layout if not forced, while Safari seems to do it at first idle time. For the comments' question about unchanged tree-model, that will indeed be implementation dependent, I don't think no specs have anything to say about that apart from being accurate when one of the reflow triggerers is called.

Comment: I suspect most browsers do have dirty flags allowing to early-exit when nothing changed (for instance if the element or one of its ancestors has `display:none`). But that's really optimizations quirks. [A related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50789614/what-exactly-updates-when-the-dom-is-manipulated/50791220#50791220).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Just wondering, if the classname has no style at all, will a simple className assignment cause the reflow?

Comment: @AGamePlayer - I'm not an expert in this area, but a quick test suggests that no, if the class you add has no style at all, adding it triggers a Recalculate Style, but not a Layout (reflow). Here's the page I used to test it: https://pastebin.com/7Ceyb7vQ If you record an interaction using the Performance tab of devtools, you can find the `oneReflow` or `twoReflow` functions and see the recalcs and layouts they trigger. I only checked Chrome, but what Chrome does seems reasonable and efficient, I'd think other browsers would be similar.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer and letting me know how you verify it. You are great!