# How to restart animation in vanilla js/ts (Angular) and support IOS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, css-animations

Hey guys I am try to create click bottom that user can click it and animation restart
as I understand it not possible and we need to destroy animation and readd it again.
So I try this way at first

HTML

```
<ul> ...
```

TS

```
    const element: HTMLUListElement = document.querySelector('.packages>.ulWrapper>ul');

    element.style.animation = 'none';
    element.offsetHeight; /* trigger reflow */
    element.style.animation = null;
```

and it work only on my desktop so I find another way

HTML

```
    <ul id="logo" class="run-animation"> ...
```

TS

```
    var element = document.getElementById("logo");

      // -> removing the class
      element.classList.remove("run-animation");
       element.offsetHeight;
      // -> and re-adding the class
      element.classList.add("run-animation");
```

And again it work perfectly on my desktop but I need it work on mobile as well

How can I do it? I am using Angular-9

Thanks guys!!

@AshishYadav I add a [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-goldberg-6ivno?file=/src/app/app.component.css)

Comment: Can you attach a working demo with your issue because it's animation stuff and it would really help us to analyze.

Comment: I did this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sVZX0XvEBhk&t=892s in my project

Comment: Your example could would have been better. Can you try to upload it on platform like CodeSandbox?

Comment: I see you are using reading an offsetHeight as an endeavour to force a reflow before you set the animation again. This [link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60361968/why-does-reading-dom-measurements-trigger-a-layout-reflow has some discussion which seems to indicate that Safari behaviour could be different from Chrome/FF.

Comment: Are you using angular? This is not how animations should be used in Angular

Comment: Yes I am using Angular, and try both approach and they work only on my pc

Comment: I try too but on this website have a lot of bugs https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-goldberg-6ivno?file=/src/app/app.component.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey guys after hard work I find a solution and I come to share it.

```
        
      const selector: string = '.packages>.ulWrapper>ul';
      const element: HTMLUListElement = document.querySelector(selector);

      element.style.animation = "none";
      element.offsetHeight; /* trigger reflow */

      setTimeout(() => element.style.animation = null, 1);
```

after you set some interval it apply the line `element.style.animation = null;`

It important you to know it support angular && smartphone include IOS

Answer (score 0):

You can use `toggle` to toggle the class in JavaScript.

```js
const element = document.getElementById("logo");

// in your click event
element.classList.toggle('run-animation');
```

Comment: If I add this after 'element.classList.add("run-animation");' nothing work and If I use it before it do nothing again on mobile it not working only desktop

Comment: You need to replace your `classList.add` and `classList.remove` and use the above code. Toggle adds / removes class.

Comment: Toggle does remove/add classes but there would then be nowhere for the code to try to force a reflow, AFAIK.

Comment: That's why I was requesting for the OP's implementation so that we can properly analyze and apply the reset. For now, I am assuming that the class has all translation and it just resets back when the class is removed, keeping things back to normal.

Comment: When I delete classList.add and classList.remove I need to do 2 clicks and it work (first to stop and second to play) but when I delete classList.remove it doesn't work

Comment: please help it doesn't work on smartphone only on PC

Comment: @LichayTiram It does work in mobile too but the way you are expecting results in mobile are different. The hover equivalent in touch devices are `touchstart` & `touchend` you need to touch the slider to pause it and touch outside somewhere to restart it. You cannot hover similar to the desktop. Hover are for devices that support mouse.

Comment: I know it, the focus should be on button that doesn't work on mobile (You can upload website to production and see it yourself - Angular)